# Shortcuts for Start and End values in the Timeline

Tags: timeline

In 2.79, it was easy to set the start and end values of the timeline with the <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> shortcuts:

If I put my green cursor at frame 42 and press <kbd>S</kbd> it sets the *Start* value at 42:

[image]

It would be great to have them re-implemented in 2.9, but before asking in the Right Click Select website I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something, for example, is it shortcutable in the Preferences?

(By the way, it would also be great if Dope Sheet and Timeline were merged into one unique window but it's another topic...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shortcuts are now:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to set **start** frame
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to set **end** frame.

Or in the *Timeline* > header menu > *Playback* > right click on the *Set Sart Frame* or *Set End Frame* buttons to create a shortcut

And you can remap it by going into `Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Animation`  and edit `Set Start Frame` and `Set End Frame`

Comment: great, thanks, or in the Preferences > Keymap > Animation > Set End Frame, and Set Start Frame

Comment: cool, edited that into my answer

Answer (score 1):

It's now <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

You can change the shortcut by right clicking the corresponding buttons (in the Timeline editor) then select "Change shortcut".

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm talking about changing the Start and End values, not moving the blue head to start or end of the timeline

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should take more time to actually read the questions ^^

Comment: no problem  ;)  maybe it was not clear enough